# Sum of Sequence inside a replace rule?

Tags: replacement, sequence

I'd like a replacement rule that replaces derivatives with their total order. I tried

```
ReplaceAll[Derivative[x__] -> Plus[x]][Derivative[1, 1]]
```

but it doesn't return 2, but `Sequence[1,1]`.

How could I get the sum of the sequence to work inside the rule?

Comment: RuleDelayed instead of Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above,

```
ReplaceAll[Derivative[x__] :> Plus[x]][Derivative[1, 1]]
```